# Delete query Java & Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estoy intentando eliminar un registro de la base con el código libro que recojo de un combo y de todas sus tablas asociadas de datos mediante `PrepareStatement` pero me está tirando un error. Os paso el código pues seguramente no esté haciendo algo correctamente.

```
private void OnEliminarLibro(ActionEvent e) {

           String aux= getRoot().getCodigoLibroEliminadosCombo().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            PreparedStatement stmtLibrosAutores = null;
            PreparedStatement stmtLibros = null;
            PreparedStatement stmtEjemplares = null;


            String consultaLibrosAutores = "DELETE codLibro FROM librosautores WHERE codLibro = ?";
            String consultaEjemplares = "DELETE codLibro FROM ejemplares WHERE codLibro = ?";
            String consultaLibros = "DELETE codLibro FROM libros WHERE codLibro = ?";

            try {
                stmtLibros = con.getCon().prepareStatement(consultaLibros);

             int result = Integer.valueOf(aux);
                 System.out.println(result);
                 stmtLibros.setInt(1,result);
                stmtLibros.executeUpdate();

                stmtLibrosAutores = con.getCon().prepareStatement(consultaLibrosAutores);
                stmtLibrosAutores.setInt(1, result);
                stmtLibrosAutores.executeUpdate();

                stmtEjemplares = con.getCon().prepareStatement(consultaEjemplares);
                stmtEjemplares.setInt(1, result);
                stmtEjemplares.executeUpdate();

                System.out.println("Eliminacion realizada");

            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

La traza del error que me está dando es la siguiente:

[image: Traza]

A continuación también les adjunto una imagen de la estructura de la Base de datos como referencia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Probar con `DELETE FROM librosautores  where codLibro = ?` ,   `DELETE FROM ejemplares where codLibro = ?` ,  `DELETE FROM libros where codLibro = ?`

Comment: Por favor, no incluyas stacktraces en imágenes. Copia y pega el texto.

Comment: vale entendido para la proxima vez

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La sintaxis de la sentencia `delete` es incorrecta, no debes incluir ningún nombre de campo; si lo piensas detenidamente no tiene sentido, puesto que se elimina toda la fila.

La sintaxis básica correcta es:

```sql
delete from Tabla [where condiciones]
```

cambia tus sentencias para que sean similares a:

```
String consultaLibrosAutores = "DELETE FROM librosautores WHERE codLibro = ?";
```

Para explicar el extraño mensaje de error y, con suerte, que el lector aprenda algo nuevo, añadiré que el motor no da error de sintaxis, porque mySQL soporta `joins` en el `delete` y puedes indicar luego de la palabra reservada `delete` el alias de la tabla que quieres borrar, por ejemplo:

```sql
delete p
  from Pedido p
       inner join Cliente c on p.idCliente = c.idCliente
 where c.Nombre = 'Juan';
```

En este hipotético caso, esto borraría todos los pedidos del cliente. (es lo que mysql llama un MULTI DELETE).

El analizador se confunde y reporta que no encuentra el alias que pusiste luego de la palabra `delete`.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por resolver la duda! a quedado todo muy claro

Comment: Es un placer, un saludo ;)

Comment: @Ricki como recomendación, sería bueno iniciar una transacción antes de ejecutar tus operaciones de delete y luego de ejecutarlas todas ejecutar un `commit`. Esto haría que tu aplicación no sufra inconsistencias de información.

Comment: Apuntado queda muchas gracias